# Multiply a Time String (HH:MM) by an Integer in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time, date-arithmetic

I wish to multiply 2 variables so that one of them is in the hour format (hh:mm),
How can I do so? The answer I am getting is 0:

```
<?php
$num = 5;
$timeUnit = "00:01";

$waitingTime = $num * $timeUnit;  
echo $waitingTime;
```

I need to get 00:05 (5 min) in the output, but I am getting 0.

Comment: What did you expect when your were multiplying **5*00:01** ?

Comment: There's no `time` variable type, there's `string`. You're multiplying a string with a number. What's your goal?

Comment: Should the `num` multiply only the minutes or also relate to the hours? (What would be the "desired" output of `5*"13:22"` ?

Comment: The num could be any number, but the timeUnit is always by minutes. for Example: 100*00:02=200min which is 3:20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you

```
$num=100;
$timeUnit="00:02";
$timeUnit;
$time=explode(":",$timeUnit);
$waitingTime=$num*$time[1];
$minute = sprintf("%02d", ($waitingTime%60));
$hour = sprintf("%02d", ($waitingTime/60));
$current_time = floor($hour).':'.($minute);
echo $current_time;
```

Comment: What if i want to multiply 1000 Rupees as per 4:30 Hrs?

Answer (score 0):

```
$num=20;
$timeUnit="00:03";
$time=explode(":",$timeUnit);
$waitingTime=$num*$time[1];
$sec=$time[0]+$waitingTime%60;
$hour=floor($waitingTime/60);
$timeUnit1="".$hour.":".$sec."";
$current=strtotime($timeUnit1); //seconds of current time
echo date("H:i",$current);
```

You can do like this

Comment: He needs to multiply not to add.

Comment: Yes I need to multiply

Comment: Not working as expected. if I am changing the time unit to : $timeUnit="00:03"; and my $num=20; my answer should be : 01:00 (HH:MM), but I am getting a different answer (3:00)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting the time into seconds, did the multiply and converted it to "time format" again:

```
$num=200;
$timeUnit="00:01:00";
$time=explode(":",$timeUnit);
$sec=$time[1]*60;
$sec=$sec*$num;

$diff = $sec;
$format = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($diff / 3600), ($diff / 60 % 60), $diff % 60);
echo $format;
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -3):

You can't compute string and digits this way.

All you would have to do would be to create a function/method that would implement the behavior you want and use it

Comment: I think he's asking how to multiply a given time in HH:MM by an integer. So, while good perspective, I think he's misguided on PHP syntax and standard libraries and simply has no idea how to multiply time.

Comment: Edited for a much simpler answer, is that it? :)

Comment: You can just do `echo 5 * "5";` it will echo 25.

Comment: @Daan that's okay for such as simple expression but what if he wanted to compute a given "HH:MM:SS" expression ? That's what I understood from his question, maybe did I go wrong